# HP Compaq 610 battery not charging

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-supply, battery

My mother has a Compaq 610 running Windows 7 Ultimate. The problem here is that it is not charging when it is plugged in. It does take power from the power supply but the battery is not charging. The power supply (from the transformer to the computer) is genuine HP and this laptop has always used that transformer, the rest (plug to transformer) I don't know.

Also, we have changed the battery and after a day the same thing starts to happen. I would appreciate any help regarding this problem and if there is anything I failed to mention please let me know.

Comment: Is you battery original HP? The most common cause is a dud battery.

Comment: Yes, it's the original one that was in the laptop intitially.. and so was the other one (in another lapotp we own same model) Also, the laptop has been with us for 4 years but what I don't get is why so suddenly... I mean when a battery is dead doesn't it degrade but still charge only less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently it was the battery.... and the other one didn't charge as it most probabbly dond't callibrate or something but it is now charging.